# How to get everything till the end of file with ANTLR?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

I'm trying to create ANTLR grammar that will parse the following input:

```
@code 123 some arbitrary text
```

I would like to split it onto three tokens: `@code`, `123` and any text after the space.. It should be something very simple, but I can't understand how to make it working..

Comment: Is it a hard requirement to use ANTLR? It looks like you could use a regex. If you do need ANTLR, does the arbitrary text need to be split into tokens or a single token?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like a good problem for antlr.

You can define tokens like AT : @[a-z+], NUMBER : [0-9]+ WORD : [a-z]+ and SIGNIFICANT_SPACE : [ ]+  WS : [\n] {skip();}

Then a grammar like ,

AT NUMBER [SIGNIFICANT_SPACE | WORD] +

and reconstruct the word and spaces, but it seems wrong.

You may also look at the [filter](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Lexical+filters) option in antlr.  You can use it to parse part of the input, then examine the character ranges of the tokens to get the parts of the line that were filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple.

```
program : start ID end;

start : '@' ID;

end : ANYTHING;

ID : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'1')*;
ANYTHING : .*;
WS : (' '|'\n'|'\r'|'\t')+ {$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

Other than that, you just need to expand on the rules to suit your purposes.

This should work with ANTLR3, but I don't know about ANTLR2.

Comment: For me this fails with "The following alternatives can never be matched: 1", referring to the line "ANYTHING : .*".